# How can I improve ARM debug process

Tags: arm, firmware

I am developing C code for an ARM development board and during the debug process while trying to locate a bug, I am doing a LOT of compile, write to the SD card, put the card in the dev board, reboot, test, put the SD card back in my PC, repeat...

I would love to find something that is like an SD card and plugs into my card reader and into my dev board where I can write to the adapter and reboot the dev board to pick up the new code.

Does anyone know of something like that?

Comment: for the raspberry pi someone had a cable solution.  at the end of the day though this is how this kind of development goes.  I assume the software loads into ram from the sd card then runs in ram?  make a small uart based bootloader, put that on the sd card, then you dont have to do the sd card dance anymore...

Comment: back in the day you used to have to pull the chip and put it in the UV eraser for a while, or stick it in a programmer and put it back.  Ideally you had multiple so you could program an erased one and take it to the board to do the next test.

Comment: You'll have to write a bit more details since ARM chips range from microcontrollers with a few kB of built-in FLASH to multicore monsters on mobile phones. Anything from JTAG to transferring code over some network might work, depending on what you have available.

Comment: What development board are you using?